# Is there a difference between control.hide/show and control.visible := false/true?

Tags: delphi

I was just wondering what might be the difference between

`TControl.Hide` and `TControl.Visible := False`

and respectively

`TControl.Show` and `TControl.Visible := True`

And if there is a difference, which one is best practice?

Comment: Why don't you use the debugger to trace into both to check?

Comment: I did that, just to find code that seems to do nothing (or at least i don't understand what it is doing) in the `.Show` procedure:
`if Parent <> nil then Parent.ShowControl(Self);` is just raised through all parents without changing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends... are you using VCL or FireMonkey? Blanc has shown you the VCL code... but FireMonkey does quite a different thing:

```
procedure TControl.SetVisible(const Value: Boolean);
var
  AlignRoot: IAlignRoot;
begin
  if FVisible <> Value then
  try
    if FVisible then
      Repaint;
    FVisible := Value;
    VisibleChanged;
  finally
    if FVisible then
      Show
    else
      Hide;
    // We notify all child controls, that parent changed visibility
    AncestorVisibleChanged(FVisible);
    if not (csLoading in ComponentState) and (Align <> TAlignLayout.None) then
    begin
      if FParentControl <> nil then
        FParentControl.Realign
      else
        if not(csLoading in ComponentState) and Supports(Parent, IAlignRoot, AlignRoot) then
          AlignRoot.Realign;
    end;
    if ParentContent <> nil then
      ParentContent.Changed;
    if FVisible then
    begin
      RecalcUpdateRect;
      Repaint;
      TAnimator.StartTriggerAnimation(Self, Self, 'IsVisible');
    end
    else
      ResetFocus;
  end;
end;
```

In this case changing the Visible property does many different things, including calling the Show or Hide methods. Also notice that in FireMonkey the default Show and Hide implementation of TControl is actually empty.

**So I'd say that with VCL you should be using Show/Hide... while with FireMonkey you should be using the Visible:=True/False**

Comment: How is this different? VCL also calls SetVisible (by setting the property Visible to true).

Comment: If you check the code, the differences are obvious. In VCL Hide/Show do more than just switch Visible... while in FireMonkey switching Visible does more than just calling Hide/Show.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, calling the Show/Hide method set the Visible property to True/False so I think there is no difference...

[TControl.Visible](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Visible)

[TControl.Hide](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Hide)

[TControl.Show](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Show)

Here is the VCL code :

```
procedure TControl.Hide;
begin
  Visible := False;
end;

procedure TControl.Show;
begin
  if Parent <> nil then Parent.ShowControl(Self);
  if not (csDesigning in ComponentState) or
    (csNoDesignVisible in ControlStyle) then Visible := True;
end;
```

Comment: Well, that's definitely more than just setting `Visible := True`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I didn't check the VCL code before my first answer. So you should use Show/Hide in VCL as Frazz said

Comment: @Jan The title of the question asks about calling `Hide`, but the body asks about calling `Show`. That lack of precision does not help.